# NSDateFormatter showing incorrect Minutes value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

below is the code i am using to get desire result for `Datetime` in iPad App,
however it gives me correct date but regarding time it is not showing correct value.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.mmm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2009-06-02 08:24:27.000"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"];
NSLog(@"Your converted date - %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Your converted date - 06/02/2009 8:00 AM

Plz note that Minutes showing is not correct... it always shows 00 value.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` ? You're reusing the "m" format for two different things, no?

Comment: Check your `date` before calling `stringFromDate`.

Comment: Just for your reference, you should probably refer to UTS documentation on date/time formatters: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are picking up two sets of values with your `mmm` format

```
HH:mm:ss.mmm
   ^^    ^^^
```

You need to use `S` for Fractional Seconds

```
HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Comment: Been there. Done that my self.

Comment: Also, accept the answer if you are happy with it 

Comment: opps was suppose to except that time only but did not allowed.... had to wait.... thx

Answer (score 0):

With this code you have the `minutes`:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
```

Sample:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2009-06-02 08:24:27.000"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"];
NSLog(@"Your converted date - %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.mmm"];
//replace above line with with below code
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```